# QLabel not sized from dimensions in designer during runtime

Tags: qt

I have a QLabel used to display a QImage. In design mode the label geometry is (9,65), 1384 × 616 as listed in the Property Editor. At runtime when the MainWindow containing the label constructs (i.e. ui->setupUi(this)), the label always appears to be 100×30 at startup which leads to images displaying only a really small portion.

Why do I have to set it to a fixed size to be anything but 100×30?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not really use the defined geometry, only the defined layouts.

Without layout and not fixed size, all components will have their default size.

So usually you need to set a layout for the container containing the component and then set the size policies of the component.

For an image, you should probably use a fixed size hint.

Comment: What criteria would you use for the fixed size?  The QLabel which is a child of the MainWindow is of indeterminate size before an image is loaded; especially on any given platform and/or monitor.  As to the other point, are you suggesting then that QLabel has a default size of 100 x 30?

Comment: I do in fact have both layout and not using fixed size.  Yet it appears that a default size (100 x 30)is in use.

Comment: Seems like I was wrong. Tried it with qt4.8 and the label keeps the size it had, without layout. With layout, the QLabel has always the same size as the widget containing it (but at least the size of the image, if set with `setPixmap`).